# Wordpress + BuddyPress + (aMembers OR Magic Members OR DAP OR ...)

Tags: wordpress

Does anybody know if there is any smooth integration between **BuddyPress** (a social networking plugin for Wordpress) with a membership plugin like **aMembers**, **Magic Members**, **DAP**, etc. (Wordpress plugins that provide Silver/Gold memberships, eCommerce, etc.)?

Would enabling BuddyPress and a membership plugin work smoothly?

Would I need to enable WPMU or just plain Wordpress will work?

Thanks!

**EDIT (24 Nov 2010, 26 Nov 2010):**

I contacted both aMembers and Magic Members support team regarding this issue.

- aMembers say "Buddy Press will work with amember/amprotect, but I haven't found a way
  of limiting access to BuddyPress features for members of X level only. If you only have 1 level of membership this may be Ok, or if it's in a walled garden."
- Magic Members say "You will need to integrate it Magic Members manually. Buddypress registration process takes over Wordpress' original registration form and Magic Members uses Wordpress' registration form which is causing a conflict. In order to avoid that we have a shortcode called [[register]]. If you put that in any of your pages the registration form will appear."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need wordpress mu (now called multisite or referred to as a network) unless you want the user to have blogs.

Also, this membership plugin works with BuddyPress:
http://www.primothemes.com/post/product/s2member-membership-plugin-with-paypal/